# CSV files being saved as XLS or nothing on download

Tags: c#, mime-types

I am trying to allow a user to download a csv file, and open it with Excel (preferably with the 'Open File with Excel' option already selected).

```
//Cont.cs
public ActionResult CSVLink(string file)
    {
        var dir = Server.MapPath("/CSV/Stats");
        var path = Path.Combine(dir, file + ".csv"); // I have tried this both with and w/o adding the csv here, and on the anchor's href instead
        return File(path, "application/csv");
    }

//Links.cshtml
<a target="_blank" href="/CSVLink?file=Hits_20150616">Today's Hits</a>
```

This mostly works, as in it allows the user to download a file, but the file extension is not keeping as csv. The issue seems to be with `return File(path, "application/csv");`, and more specifically `application/csv`.

Here's a list of what happens with various mime types:

- `application/csv` - The file downloads, but does not have a file extension
- `text/csv` - same
- `application/binary` - same
- `application/vnd.ms-excel` - The file downloads as an .xls file, which messes up how it looks in Excel.

Here's another weird thing: All the files that don't have extensions, if I rename them and put the .csv on the end, they open in Excel looking perfect. This happens in both IE and Firefox (except for `octet-stream`, that makes it open as plain text in a new webpage).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the question a wee bit: you have a file named `/CSV/Stats/SomeFileName.csv` and you're wanting to serve that content out to the user, correct?  But I don't see where you're reading the bytes from the file, in order to serve up the content - you're serving up a file, which isn't right, unless you were to serve up a redirect to `/CSV/Stats/SomeFileName.csv`  If you're not serving up a redirect, you'd need to do something like:

```
var s = File.ReadAllText(path);
return File(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s.ToString()), "text/csv", file + ".csv");
```

Lastly: it's probably a bad thing to use `file` as your parameter name, there - it's at least misleading, and at worst going to cause confusion.

Comment: Reading the bytes from the file? I don't think this is what I want to do. I want them to click a link and have them download the csv file. This setup I have works with pdf's, so it should work with csv's too. I think it's a matter of having the correct mime­type.

Comment: Hmm.  When I'm returning a file, generically, I also just pluck it from the file system and hand it over - in my case, it's stored in the file system, as yours appears to be.  The mime-type you have is correct for text/csv ... but the only text/csv I return from my particular solution is coming from memory, rather than a file - the other files I serve up are of application/octet-stream.  Think it's worth a try reading it out & returning it?